# View MongoDB array in order of indices with Compass

Tags: mongodb-compass

I am working on a database of Polish verbs and I'd like to find out how to display my results such that each verb conjugation appears in the following order: 1ps (1st person singular), 2ps, 3ps, 1ppl (1st person plural, etc.), 2ppl, 3ppl. It displays fine when I insert documents:

[verb "żyć/przeżyć" conjugation as array and nested document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS9X3.png)

But when I go to perform queries it jumbles all the array elements up, in the first case (I want to see them in order of array indices), and sorts the nested document elements into alphabetical order (whereas I want to see them in the order in which they were inserted).

[verb "żyć/przeżyć" conjugation array/document query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8TLX.png)

This should be an easy one to solve, I hope this comes across as a reasonable beginner's question. I have searched for answers but couldn't find much info on this topic. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
LC.

Comment: Can you also show the relevant code, it's hard to divine what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshots highlight two different views in MongoDB Compass.

The Schema view is based on a sampling of multiple documents and the order of the fields displayed cannot be specified. The schema analysis (as at Compass 1.7) lists fields in case-insensitive alphabetical order with the `_id` field at the top. Since this is an aggregate schema view based on multiple documents, the ordering of fields is not expected to reflect individual document order.

[image: Schema view]

If you want to work with individual documents and field ordering you need to use the Documents view, as per your second screenshot. In addition to displaying the actual documents, this view allows you to include `sort` and `skip` options for queries:

[image: Documents view]